# ngIf in angular 2 not working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ng-if

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
  <div *ngIf="message.user===user">

  </div>

 <input [(ngModel)]="message"  />
<button (click)="sendMessage()">Send</button>
```

Here user is the variable that I have assigned in the component. That is a string value 'user1'. If `message.user === user1` then I need to show something but its not working.

Comment: What are the values of `message.user` and `user`?

Comment: Please add your componet.ts code.

Comment: Debug your code. Add an output statement `VALUS ARE '{{message.user}}' and 'user'}}` to your template. Anyway, what are you expecting to happen? The `div` you have the `*ngIf` on is empty.. Also, your top `div` is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current code block, you are binding `message`(object instance) to `input` with `[(ngModel)]` in `*ngFor`, this will lead to [error](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8602).

also when you type one character in `input`, it will turn `message`(object) to string and then lose the original fields(such as `user`). Maybe this is the reason for your current situation.

here is simple **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5vvbV83WCqKqQwMwP4C0?p=preview)** may help get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

you need basic code like this...at least.

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
  <div *ngIf="message.user === user">
      user: {{ message.user }}
  </div>
</div>
<input [(ngModel)]="message"  />
<button (click)="sendMessage()">Send</button>
```

Your component should have 'messages' prop as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided some demo ..since u failed to add your .ts file just go through this:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys that error was just because i missed out closing one div thanks for your responses